# How to solve $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2+k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can someone show me what is wrong with the expression I got for evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2+k}$?
Steps:

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2+k} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^2+k} =  \frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}{n^3+\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^3+n(n+1)} = \frac{n+1}{2n^2+n+1}$

However, when I plug in something like $\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{k}{10^2+k}$ into this [online summation calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=dfaf1b7d15e572ae5a1b2fa172ce8657&title=Math+Help+Boards%3A+Sum+Calculator&theme=blue), the answer I get is $\sim0.514$, which is not the same answer I get with $\frac{10+1}{2(10)^2+10+1} = \frac{11}{211} \approx 0.0521$

Comment: How would you justify this step: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^2+k}$ ?

Comment: @Tintarn I thought it was correct by property 4 [here](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/CS202-Subunit-4.2.4-Summation_FINAL.pdf)? Clearly I was mistaken, but then what does number 4 actually mean on that page?

Comment: In property 4, one sum uses _i_ as index, while the other uses _j_ while the summation on the right has no indices, which is rather suspect. As there are no examples given, I have difficulty understanding what either formula 3 or formula 4 mean. Are these infinite sums? If so, a condition should be that the sums converge.

Comment: @BernardMasse: I suppose Formula 3 actually means $(\sum_{1 \le i \le n} a_i)(\sum_{1 \le j \le n} b_j)=\sum_{1 \le i,j \le n} a_ib_j$ which makes sense for any positive $n$ and also for $n=\infty$ if both sides converge. But IMHO, formula 4 is completely wrong (in any such interpretation of the indices)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's equal to $n - n^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2 + k}$. Now use Harmonic sum to solve the rest.

Comment: How did you get to $n - n^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2 + k}$? I see how you could use harmonic sum approximation to solve the rest, but I'm not sure how you got there in the first place..

Comment: $k=n^2-n^2+k = n^2+k-n^2$

Answer (score 3):

Your first step is wrong:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k} \neq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{\sum_{k=1}^n n^2+k}$$

It's like saying $\frac ab + \frac cd=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ which is false...

Comment: That's weird, because I was reading about summation properties [here](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/CS202-Subunit-4.2.4-Summation_FINAL.pdf) and I thought that it was correct by property 4. Could you possibly take a look at that page and explain what property 4 actually means, and maybe a hint on the correct solution for this summation?

Comment: It's false. I guess they made an error while writing the article... See @Alex's answer for a hint to the right solution...

Comment: I see, I assume that means number 3 is false as well, right?

Comment: The $\sum$ there donates a double sum,which means that you first sum by $j$ then by $i$.This applies to both $3$ and $4$.